# I am having difficulty converting a non-square image to a square using python opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have the image below, and I know the coordinate values ​​of p0, p1, p2, p3.

[image]

I want to convert it as below using python opencv.

[image]

I wrote the following code, but the desired result does not come out.

```py
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = 'img/path.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
height, width, ch = img.shape
points = some_magical_point_detector(img)

temp = []

for idx, p in enumerate(points):
    p1 = points[idx]
    p2 = points[(idx+1) % 4]
    d = math.sqrt( ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2) )
    temp.append(d)

size = max(temp)



dst_points = np.float32([[0, 0], [size, 0], [0, size], [size, size]])


M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points, dst_points)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (width, height))

plt.imshow(dst)
plt.title('Affine')
plt.show()
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please describe the error.

Comment: Also, code is not runnable, please refer to [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure what the problem is because you haven't written what goes wrong or what is the result of your code but I'm guessing that you forgot to transform the "`some_magical_point_detector()`" coordinates to `np.float32` type (the same way you did with variable `dst_points`.

I have modified your code to show an example of what you probably missed, what would your result be, what should your result look like and what you probably need based on the image that you posted as desired result.

Code:

```
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np


def some_magical_point_detector(img):
    orange_low = np.array([5, 50, 50], np.uint8)
    orange_high = np.array([15, 255, 255], np.uint8)

    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    orange_thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, orange_low, orange_high)

    thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(
        orange_thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((25, 25), np.uint8))
    contours = cv2.findContours(
        thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
    cnt = max(contours, key=lambda c: cv2.contourArea(c))

    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    return cnt, box


path = '3.png'
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
h, w = img.shape[:2]

cnt, points = some_magical_point_detector(img)
cv2.drawContours(img, [np.int0(points)], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

points = np.float32(points)  # Probably forgot this line


temp = []
for idx, p in enumerate(points):
    p1 = points[idx]
    p2 = points[(idx+1) % 4]
    d = math.sqrt(((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2))
    temp.append(d)

size = max(temp)

# What you are trying to do
your_dst_points = np.float32([[0, 0], [size, 0], [0, size], [size, size]])

# What should be
dst_points = np.float32([(w, h), (0, h), (0, 0), (w, 0)])

M_mine = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points, dst_points)
M_yours = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(points, your_dst_points)

mine_dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M_mine, (w, h))
your_dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M_yours, (w, h))


# What you need
box = np.int0(points)
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)

angle = rect[2]
shape = (w, h)
center = (w//2, h//2)

matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center=center, angle=angle, scale=1)
res = cv2.warpAffine(src=img, M=matrix, dsize=shape,
                    borderValue=(255, 255, 255))


cv2.imshow("original", img)
cv2.imshow("mine_dst", mine_dst)
cv2.imshow("your_dst", your_dst)
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.imwrite("original.png", img)
cv2.imwrite("mine_dst.png", mine_dst)
cv2.imwrite("your_dst.png", your_dst)
cv2.imwrite("res.png", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]